# How to determine if image is hyperlinked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have a css class being applied to all links within a div with class "linkroll":

```
var selector = '.linkroll a';
```

I am trying to prevent this class being added to any hyperlinked images within the div. How do I do this?

Like, I wouldn't want this to have the class applied:

```
<div class="linkroll"><a href="#somelink"><img src="someimg.jpg"></a></div>

var selector = '.linkroll a';
// if selector is not image, then do something...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can only go down the DOM tree, so you cannot add a class based on child elements, only parents. However you could use jQuery do this with a `filter()`:

```
$('.linkroll a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('img').length == 0;
}).addClass('foo');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/SwCrZ/)

Answer (score 0):

$('.linkroll a').filter(function() {

```
return $(this).attr('href');
```

}).parent().removeClass('linkroll');

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SwCrZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a css class being applied to all links within a div with class "linkroll"

which means it's already applied, so I suppose now you want to get rid of that class:

**[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/uweqeV/2/edit)**

```
$('.linkroll a > img').closest('div').removeClass('linkroll');
```